# Bootstrap carousel prevents anchor tags to work

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Since I added a bootstrap carousel to my website, all the a tags suddenly stopped working. Does anyone know how I can fix it? Here's my code.

```css
body {} .nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1%;
  background-color: #d2d6d5;
  z-index: 5;
}
.awesomelinks {
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 7%;
  display: inline;
  z-index: 2;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
.awesomelinks:hover {
  color: rgba(57, 196, 232, 1.00);
  font-size: 18px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#about {
  margin-left: 0%;
}
.thingy {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  width: 100%;
}
.carousel {
  position: asbolute;
  top: 24px;
}
.first-slide {
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
.second-slide {
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
.third-slide {
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="nav">
  <a href="About-Us.html" class="awesomelinks" id="about">About         Us</a>
  <a href="Donations.html" class="awesomelinks" id="donate">Donate</a>
  <a href="Our-Team.html" class="awesomelinks" id="team">Our Team</a>
  <a href="Media.html" class="awesomelinks" id="media">Media</a>
  <a href="mailto:utunicyclingsociety@gmail.com" target="_blank" id="contact" class="awesomelinks">Contact Us  <img src="Jump Around.gif"/>                </a>
</div>
<div class="thingy">
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class=""></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1" class=""></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2" class="active"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item">
        <img class="first-slide" src="http://www.brucebeckphotography.com/data/photos/631_1090818_5582_85_pano.jpg" alt="First slide">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h1>Utah Unicycling Society</h1>
            <p>Text here</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img class="second-slide" src="http://www.brucebeckphotography.com/data/photos/631_1090818_5582_85_pano.jpg" alt="Second slide">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h1></h1>
            <p></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item active">
        <img class="third-slide" src="http://www.brucebeckphotography.com/data/photos/631_1090818_5582_85_pano.jpg" alt="Third slide">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h1></h1>
            <p></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>
</div>
```

I t would be a huge help if anybody helped me on this. Thank you so much.

Comment: Where is the tag code , I cant see any tag code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a simple CSS error. Remove `position: absolute` and `top: 0%` from the CSS class `thingy`, like that :

```
.thingy {
  /* position: absolute; */
  /* top: 0%; */
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you .thingy class is overlapping with the links! So either place them little lower or increase the Z-index of Nav higher than thingy.!

```
.nav {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

OR

```
.thingy {
 top:24px;
}
```

and your remove your below code

```
.carousel {
  position: asbolute;
  top: 24px; 
}
```